# How to export a fetch result to another file

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await, fetch

I am new to promises and async/await in React environment.

I am getting `undefined` in `Searchbar.js` when I am returning the result of a fetch request.

**Searchbar.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {getSearchResults} from './unsplashAPI';

const Searchbar = (props) => {
    const onSearch = (e) =>  {
        const searchQuery = e.target.value;
        const searchResults = getSearchResults(searchQuery);
        console.log(searchResults);
    }

    return <TextField onChange={onSearch}/>
};

export default Searchbar;
```

**unsplashAPI.js**:

```js
const AccessKey = '**redacted**';
const rootURL = 'https://api.unsplash.com/';

// get search results
const getSearchResults = (query) => {
    fetch(`${rootURL}/search/photos?client_id=${AccessKey}&query=${query}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {}
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(response => {
        return response.results;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}

export {getSearchResults};
```

Comment: Do you get any errors while fetching data? Is fetch response `200 OK`? Did you try to manually request Unsplash API in your browser?

Comment: You don't `return` anything from `getSearchResults`. (All the `return` keywords there are inside `then` callbacks).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. That what I was missing.